# Vue.js infinite Scroll

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I wondering if there is any directive for implementing Ajax infinite scroll with vue.js or is there any directive available ?

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Based on some tutorial code I used, the following demonstrates how to add a listener in a Vue.js component to the scroll event and a method to do something if the user scrolls to the bottom of the window.

Note that when doing `window.addEventListener`, you must remove it using `window.removeEventListener`.

Maybe this can help you get started.

```
created: function () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
},
destroyed: function () {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
},
methods: {
    handleScroll: function () {
        this.scrollPos = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight - document.body.scrollTop;   
        if (document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight - document.body.scrollTop == 0) {
            // load more data here...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with any directive.
You need to listen to scroll event and ajax additional items when the user hits bottom of the window/container.

Answer (score -3):

All jquery components can be integrated with Vue through directives. But if you want people to help, you should provide a jsfiddle example.